# GWT HTTP Response getText() as Binary

Tags: javascript, gwt, get, request, httprequest

I'm working on a GWT App that makes a REST call for **binary** data. I'm trying to use GWT's RequestBuilder. The problem is that the response only offers a getText() method.

Here's the simplest example that reproduces the problem:

```
private static void sendRequest()
{
    String url = URL.encode("/object/object_id");

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
    try
    {
        requestBuilder.sendRequest("", new RequestCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
            {
                String data = response.getText(); ///< Need this to be a byte[] array (e.g. getData())
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
            {
            }
        });
    }
    catch (RequestException RequestException)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that GWT is encoding the response data as a String in (what I think) is the default platform's encoding. Is there any way to get the data before GWT converts it to a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP can transfer text and binary, but Javascript can only get text via XHR. If you want to send binary data through it then [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode it. GWT can [handle Base64](http://snipt.net/tweakt/gwt-base64/).

**Update:** in recent browsers (end of 2013), the binary array handling can be achieved via [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). See [browser support](http://caniuse.com/typedarrays) for it.

Comment: I suspected as much. We'll have to modify our API to base 64 encode the data prior to return it.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. HTTP can transfer binary data. A common example are images.

Comment: Yes, I should make it clearer: HTTP can download and upload binary, buy binary is not available to Javascript and hence GWT.

Comment: Binary is available to JS and GWT thru modern browsers. See TypedArrays and lib-gwt-file from org.vectomatic

Comment: Yes, TypedArrays are a relatively recent addition. They were not supported in mainstream browsers when I wrote the answer. Updating..

Answer (score 1):

You can get binary image in GWT using JSNI. Mind that it doesn't work with IE.
This is an example how:

```
native String getBinaryResource(String url) /*-{
    // ...implemented with JavaScript                 
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);  // The last parameter determines whether the request is asynchronous -> this case is sync.
    req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    req.send(null);
    if (req.status == 200) {                    
        return req.responseText;
    } else return null
}-*/;
```

I just finished researching a similar question where I put additional information: 
[Generating an inline-image with java gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409587/generating-an-inline-image-with-java-gwt/6495356#6495356)